# C++ Feeding strings from a text document as arguments

Tags: c++, getline

Is there a way to feed strings from a text document directly as arguments? Preferably without saving them?

I have a killProcessByName method that is expecting an argument so I was wondering if it is possible to read the first line from my text document, copy it then send it as an argument? Then move on to the next line, preform the same thing and repeat the process until there are no words left in the document?

Example of my list:

```
Apples.exe
Blueberries.exe
Watermelon.exe
Oranges.exe
...
```

The method I'm targeting

```
void killProcessByName(const char *filename)
{
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    while (hRes)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                                          (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID);
            if (hProcess != NULL)
            {
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
        hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}
```

Comment: Like `while(read_string(string_var)) { function(string_var); }`?

Comment: Argument to what? Free function taking no other arguments? Method call taking no other arguments? Function or method call taking several other arguments as follows (give precise details of what and when)? Command line utility? Something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please post your trials and errors in a [MCVE]? We can't help much without providing further information ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @FirstStep thank you for the recommendation I updated my original post with the method I'm targeting.

Comment: `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` is quite expensive, and so is looping over all the processes in a snapshot.  You should read your file into a `std::unordered_set<std::string>`, and then loop over all the processes _once_ and see if any of their executables matches _any_ of the names in the set.  That will be much more efficient, particularly when the list of programs to kill is long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout, std::endl
#include <fstream>  // std::ifstream
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // open your file
    ifstream input_file("test.txt");

    // create variables
    string name;

    // while there are entries
    while(input_file >> name)
    {
        killProcessByName(name.c_str());
    }

   // close the file
   input_file.close();

   return 0;
}
```